# Removing attribute with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm facing a little problem with jQuery. My navbar have links that became blue when they are selected ('active' attribute), I can add attributes until now, but when I click on another link I can't remove the last one correctly. I wrote some code, I'll be thankful if anyone could help me.

//jQuery

```
   jQuery('.navbar-nav').on('click', ' li > a.ajaxify', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        App.scrollTop();

        var url = $(this).attr("href");
        var menuContainer = jQuery('.navbar-nav');
        var pageContent = $('.page-content');
        var pageContentBody = $('.page-content .page-content-body');

        menuContainer.children('li.active').removeClass('active');
        menuContainer.children('arrow.open').removeClass('open');
        menuContainer.children('arrow.open').removeClass('open');

        $(this).parents('li').each(function () {
            $(this).addClass('active');
            $(this).children('a > span.arrow').addClass('open');
        });
        $(this).parents('li').addClass('active');

        App.blockUI(pageContent, false);

        ...
    });
```

//HTML

```
<li class="active">
    <a href="" class="ajaxify" id="startLoadTag">
        <i class="fa fa-home"></i> Link
    </a>
</li>
<li class="">
    <a href="" class="ajaxify">
        <i class="fa fa-puzzle-piece"></i> Link
    </a>
</li>
<li class="">
    <a data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown" data-close-others="true" class="dropdown-toggle" href="">
        <i class="fa fa-quote-right"></i>
        Evento
        <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li>
            <a href="" class="ajaxify"><i class="fa fa-building"></i> Link</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="" class="ajaxify"><i class="fa fa-lightbulb-o"></i> Link</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="" class="ajaxify"><i class="fa fa-suitcase"></i> Link</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="" class="ajaxify"><i class="fa fa-group"></i> Link</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="" class="ajaxify"><i class="fa fa-comments"></i> Link</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, just did it and everything worked just fine. Thanks all.

```
menuContainer.children('li.active').removeClass('active');
menuContainer.children('arrow.open').removeClass('open');

$('ul').each(function() {
    $(this).children('li').each(function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        }
    });
});

$(this).parents('li').addClass('active');
```

Answer (score 0):

Before this line

> `$(this).parents('li').addClass('active');`

you need to run an `.each` function for every 'active' class and remove the class.
Maybe something like this

```
 $('li').each(function() { 
if($(this).hasClass('active') { 
   $(this).removeClass('active'); 
}); 
}
```

Comment: You certainly don't !

Comment: Yeah my bad , try this
 $('li').each(function() {
if($(this).hasClass('active')
{
                    $(this).removeClass('active');
                });
}

Comment: Still nothing. Now the Ajax do not load the content in the right place.

Comment: Create another class that its only used to highlight the selected object / item and doesn't position the object